Running through all pages
I'm making a peoplefinder app that will be free. It will look through all the people in Texas by name, and find their home address. I just got started, and can't seem to figure out how cycling through all the pages would work. Is there a good, reliable way to do this? Am I just dumb? This is my first big project, and I could really use some help.
import json
from time import sleep

name = input("Enter full name: ")

def namesearchwilcounty(name):
    url = "https://search.wcad.org/ProxyT/Search/Properties/quick/"
    params = {
        "f": name,
        "pn": 1,
        "st": 4,
        "so": "desc",
        "pt": "RP;PP;MH;NR",
        "ty": "2024"
    }

    response = requests.get(url, params=params)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        if data and "ResultList" in data and data["ResultList"]:
            print("Situs Addresses and Owner Names:")
            processed_results = set()  # Set to store processed results
            for item in data["ResultList"]:
                situs_address = item["SitusAddress"]
                owner_name = item["OwnerName"]
                total_page_count = item.get("TotalPageCount", 1)
                current_page = 1
                while current_page <= total_page_count:
                    params["pn"] = current_page  # Update the page number in params
                    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
                    if response.status_code == 200:
                        page_data = response.json()
                        for item in page_data["ResultList"]:
                            situs_address = item["SitusAddress"]
                            owner_name = item["OwnerName"]
                            result = f"{owner_name} {situs_address}"
                            if result not in processed_results:
                                print(f"Page {current_page}: {result}")
                                processed_results.add(result)  # Add result to the set
                        current_page += 1
                        sleep(1)  # Add a delay between requests
                    else:
                        print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
                        break
        else:
            print("No data found in the response.")
    else:
        print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")


namesearchwilcounty(name)


It would help if you said what the exact problem is, instead of just "I'm having a hard time".

Trying your code, I always get no more than 1 page of 25 results no matter what name I use.  The API doesn't seem to return more than that.

first visit few pages in browser and see what parameters browser sends to server. You could also check if you can load other page in browser when you change some parameter. And check if you can visit pages with much bigger numbers. Some servers sends only few pages - maybe because portals are created for people, and people are tired after few pages so there is no need to generate pages with bigger numbers. OR maybe it is method to stop spamers/hackers/scrapers to get all data.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It seems that the pn parameters is a page number (base 1) and that no more pages are available when the RecordCount is zero.
So, simplifying your code, you could do this:
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter, Retry

URL = "https://search.wcad.org/ProxyT/Search/Properties/quick/"

MAX_RETRIES = 5
RETRIES = Retry(total=MAX_RETRIES, status_forcelist=[429])

def search(name):
    params = {
        "f": name,
        "pn": 1,
        "st": 4,
        "so": "desc",
        "pt": "RP;PP;MH;NR",
        "ty": "2024"
    }
    with requests.Session() as session:
        session.mount(URL, HTTPAdapter(max_retries=RETRIES))
        while True:
            with session.get(URL, params=params) as response:
                response.raise_for_status()
                data = response.json()
                if (record_count := data.get("RecordCount", 0)) == 0:
                    print("No more records")
                    break
                print(f"current_page={params["pn"]} {record_count=}")
                params["pn"] += 1

search("Kennedy")

Output:
current_page=1 record_count=25
current_page=2 record_count=25
current_page=3 record_count=25
current_page=4 record_count=25
current_page=5 record_count=25
current_page=6 record_count=25
current_page=7 record_count=9
No more records

